# Looking for a copy of SNOMED CT

Tags: dataset

I am a student who is interested in learning and researching SNOMED CT.

However, I do not have the permission to download it. Is there anyone who can give me a copy, even if it is an old one? I would be very grateful for your help.

Thank you,

BTW, my email: kergee(at)gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are resident in the UK, you can register with the NHS TRUD service at  https://isd.digital.nhs.uk/trud where you'll find the UK SNOMED CT releases and, subject to accepting the licensing conditions, you can download an RF2 format copy.